# Primefaces file upload - file without extension

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

I am using Primefaces v6.2.13 to upload a file. Works fine for files with extension, but crashes when trying to upload file without extension.

This is the part of xhtml used to render upload button

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{addFileController.file}"
    mode="simple" skinSimple="true"
    rendered="#{!addFileController.uploadDisable}"
    label="Choose file"
    allowTypes="#{addfileController.allowedTypes}" />
```

When I choose file, nothing happens, but as soon as I click the upload button, it throws an error, that I am unable to catch in my code, since it first calls some upload mechanism in PrimeFaces and later the code that I wrote.

The error is:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: File must have an extension
    at org.primefaces.util.FileUploadUtils.getValidFilename(FileUploadUtils.java:54)
```

and the problematic part of the code inside class looks like this

```
...
String name = FilenameUtils.getName(filename);
String extension = FilenameUtils.EXTENSION_SEPARATOR_STR + FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename);

if (extension.isEmpty()) {
    throw new FacesException("File must have an extension");
}
....
}
```

Any idea how to deal with this? I was thinking about adding some attribute to xhtml to disable uploading files without extension, since I don't want to edit PF source code.

Comment: Yeah that check as added to to server side checking of allowTypes etc for security.  Are you sure you want to upload files wiithout extensions?   If you do feel strongly about this I recommend reporting it as an issue on the GitHub page https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues

Comment: ACtually, I want to disable uploading of files without extensions. Now I wonder if my allowedTypes variable was not empty. I'll check that and let you know